# Since I created a GMail account, login onto Stack Exchange sites using Google creates a new account instead of using the previous one

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist)

I previously created my Google Reader account using an xxx@hotmail.com email.
Recently I've created an xxx@gmail.com email, Google tells me that I can log with any of them on their services.

By convenience I do now log on using my new xxx@gmail.com but I've just discovered that using this new email address to log on to Stack Exchange web sites, the service do create a new account instead of fetching the usual one.

Is it possible to merge my accounts or something like it ?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist